# How to get current queries to max_concurrent_queries

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I encountered this error：

`clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 202. DB::Exception: Too many simultaneous queries. Maximum: 200. Stack trace:`

but I have adjusted the max_concurrent_queries from 100 to 200.

I need to know the current number of queries. If it is about to exceed the max_concurrent_queries, the program will no longer search but wait.
But I have looked at the indicators in the system.metrics, system.events, and system.asynchronous_metrics tables and no suitable monitoring indicators were found.

Please help me, I want to achieve the maximum number of searches within the current max_concurrent_queries allowed range of clickhouse.

Comment: I tried monitoring with `SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM system.processes`, but the result never exceeded 20 until the error occurred. Could it be that a certain query momentarily spiked to over 200? Should I use a different method to monitor this, or is there another approach I should consider for tracking query counts more effectively?

Comment: I would just add that the cause of this issue is rarely the setting max_concurrent_queries. The error TOO MANY SIMULTANEOUS QUERIES is almost always a symptom, not a cause. The cause is typically that the ClickHouse server/service is not responding fast enough, so there is a backlog of activities and concurrent queries are slowed down and therefore concurrent connections are increasing. In this situation, no value for max_concurrent_queries is high enough, and in fact - lowering this value can be more effective in order to protect the server/service from overload (that is the reason it exists)

Comment: I understand the reason for the problem, but if I can monitor the current concurrent connections, I may be able to pause the query task and wait before it crashes.

Comment: I tryed this: `select * from system.metrics where metric like '%Connection%';`, I found that `Too many simultaneous queries` will occur when `TCPConnection` exceeds 500, but I don’t know what the relationship between the `200` set by `max_concurrent_queries` and `TCPConnection` is. I will use `TCPConnection` to control query congestion for the time being.

Comment: Maybe you just don't close connections in your code?

Comment: Well, that was the problem - 
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/56659#issuecomment-1809657463

Comment: @Pavel Kravtso, I forgot to reply a few days ago. I'm really sorry. This is the question I asked on github. Thank you very much for your attention to this issue and your enthusiastic help in finding the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of queries currently running, run this:

```
select count() from system.processes
```

If you want to track the `Number of executing queries` metrics, you can use the `ClickHouseMetrics_Query` [gauge](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#prometheus), or you can directly select the value of the metric from [metrics table](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/metrics):

```
select value from system.metrics where metric = 'Query'
```

Comment: You're welcome! I've tried the search you suggested, but during the process of reproducing the error, the number of queries never exceeded 20. Could it be that a certain query briefly spiked to over 200? If so, how can I monitor the number of such queries and ensure that it stays below 200 while inputting as many queries as possible?

Comment: （The above is from a translation, and there may be some inappropriate wording. Please don't mind）

Comment: How do you execute the metrics select? If done manually, there is a chance that the spike occurs between your manual executions. Additionally, how do you execute all other queries? Do you have access to the code and the ability to modify it?

Comment: I want to see how crowded the current query is through monitoring. I guess there should be a value. When it exceeds the threshold, this error will appear. I want to monitor the value. If it is about to exceed the threshold, I will wait for a while before executing the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Some queries may trigger multiple sub-queries. Once a query triggers multiple sub-queries, it is hard to track them over `system.processes` table, since they will start to fail once the limit is reached.

I would recommend to use `system.query_log` table to check those queries. It may help to understand why queries are spiking.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_log

```
with time_range as (
  select now() - interval number second time_to_check
  from numbers(3600)
),
query_log as (
  select hostName() host_name, query_start_time, event_time, type, query, query_kind
  from clusterAllReplicas('{cluster}', system.query_log)
  where event_date=today()
  and type != 'QueryStart'
)
select
  host_name,
  time_to_check, 
  count()
from query_log
cross join time_range
where time_range.time_to_check >= query_log.query_start_time
  and time_range.time_to_check <  query_log.event_time
group by time_to_check
order by time_to_check;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does provide another way of thinking